# ggplot2 stat_density_2d: how to fix polygon errors at the dataset bounding box edges?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stat-density2d

I am analysing my sfc_POINT dataset using `ggplot2::stat_density_2d`. I seems, though, that the resulting polygons get all wonky at the edge of the dataset bounding box. For whatever reason, ggplot2 can't seem to draw polygons further than the source dataframe edges.

How do I fix the density polygons? Is there a way to extend the bounding box for `stat_density_2d` somehow?

For this question I am able to reproduce my problem with a random sample point data. Please see the code here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(geofi)
library(ggplot2)

# Finland municipalities
muns <- geofi::get_municipalities(year = 2022)

# Create sample points
points <- sf::st_sample(muns, 50) %>% as.data.frame()
points[c("x", "y")] <- sf::st_coordinates(points$geometry)

p4 <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = muns) +
  coord_sf(default_crs = sf::st_crs(3067)) +
  stat_density_2d(geom = "polygon", 
                  data = points, 
                  aes(x = x, y = y, fill = ..level..), 
                  alpha = 0.75) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  geom_point(data = points, aes(x = x, y = y), alpha = 0.5)
p4
```

[image: density2d polygons get all wonky if they reach the bounding box determined by datapoints in most extreme locations]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "crazy polygons" phenomenon was an old problem that was often encountered when this method (calculating polygons via `stat_density2d`) was the only option. It was was remediated by the addition of `geom_density2d_filled` in ggplot2 v3.3.2

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = muns) +
  coord_sf(default_crs = sf::st_crs(3067)) +
  geom_density2d_filled(
                  data = points, 
                  aes(x = x, y = y), 
                  alpha = 0.75) +
  geom_point(data = points, aes(x = x, y = y), alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

If you want to cover the whole range of `muns` rather than just the range of `points`, you can pre-calculate the density yourself over the bounding box of `muns` and pass that to `geom_contour_filled`:

```r
d <- MASS::kde2d(points$x, points$y, lims = st_bbox(muns)[c(1, 3, 2, 4)])
dens <- data.frame(expand.grid(x = d$x, y = d$y), z = as.vector(d$z))

ggplot() +
  geom_contour_filled(data = dens, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z, 
                                       alpha = after_stat(level))) +
  geom_sf(data = muns, fill = NA, color = "black") +
  coord_sf(default_crs = sf::st_crs(3067), expand = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data = points, aes(x = x, y = y), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0, rep(0.75, 7)), guide = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Allan, many thanks for your fast answer. Your proposition to use `geom_contour_filled` solves 90 % of my problem and I am prepared to accept your answer. However, initially I chose to use `stat_density_2d` because it left areas of zero density transparent. Is there some convenient way to achieve this with `geom_density2d_filled`?